# Uncaught error: TypeError: data.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Could you please help me here?
I want to map through a response object (example below). I don't have any errors in VSC but in browser there is an error:
Uncaught error: TypeError: data.map is not a function

```
{
  "title":"some title",
  "info":"some info",
  "users":
  [
    {
      "id":1,
      "name":"name1",
      "surname":"surname1",
      "email":"email1",
    },
    {
      "id":2,
      "name":"name2",
      "surname":"surname2",
      "email":"email2",
    },
 ....
  ],
"resource":
{
  "url":"some url",
  "description":"some description"
  }
}
```

here is my interfaces:

```
export interface IUsers {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  surname: string,
  email: string
}

export interface IData {
  title: string,
  info: string,
  users: IUsers,
  resource: {
    url: string,
    description: string
  }
}
```

What i've got for now:

```
const { data } = DataAPI.useFetchAllDataQuery('')
...
{data  && data.map(item => item.users.map(user => (
 <User user={user} key={user.id}/>)))}
```

should i try `data.users.map(...)` --> property 'users' doesn't exist on type IData[].

May be it's because of the fact that 'data' is not an array, but i'm not sure how to use this construction Object.entries(data).map()...

Comment: Hello @Elizabeth in your {data  && data.map(item => item.users.map(user => (
 <User user={user} key={user.id}/>)))} you have misspelled item.users. (users attribute does not exists in your interface IData). It should be item => item.data.map [...] Attribute is "data" check it. I hope it helps. Best luck

Comment: @Sam: Are you sure ? users attribute does not exists in your interface IData ?

Comment: Hello @Sam. Thank you for your answer. I accidentally made a mistake while transferring data here and already corrected that typo. Should you have any other ideas please tell me

Comment: data.map? Should it be data.users.map? (Map is an array function not an object function)

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `DataAPI.useFetchAllDataQuery('')`? Since this is a fetch request, it's definitely a side effect and you should be using the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook.

Comment: @Elizabeth If your data having a response of type `[IData]` or data.users will be `[IUsers]` then .map() function will work as it works only for arrays not for objects.

Comment: @JuanMarco i called it inside FC. if i do it inside useEffect() got an error: React Hook "DataAPI.useFetchAllDataQuery" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try doing something like this?

```
const { data } = await DataAPI.useFetchAllDataQuery('') // Assuming this is a promise
{data && data.users.map(user => (<User user={user} key={user.id}>))}
```

or maybe optional chaining

```
{data?.users?.map(user => (<User user={user} key={user.id}>))}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried. property 'users' doesn't exist on type IData[]. for some reasons it doesn't see it

Comment: Hmmm. strange, can you try using optional chaining and see the output? I've edited my answer above

Comment: unfortunately the same error.  it does know that 'data' typeof IData[] | undefined but it  doesn't see 'users' inside.

Comment: Final thing. When you query the data, did you `await` the promise?

`const { data } = await DataAPI.useFetchAllDataQuery('')`

Comment: thank you for another idea but i'm not sure if it's required here. i receive the object from the server, i just can't iterate through because of the types. 'users' is definitely inside, i can see it, but when i refer it through dot notation it says property doesn't exist on type..

Comment: Yeah because what I'm thinking is, if you're getting data asynchronously. There's a split second where `{ data }` , which is being destructured directly, is undefined, so you're gonna have to `await` the promise for you to destructure `{data}`. If you are importing data synchronously then I'm stumped as to what we can do here.

Comment: it didn't make it asynhronous. if i do: ts says await has no effect on type and if i make the whole component async, it becomes not valid jsx. but now when i tried to display stringified object it didn't work,  it showed me it in console only. so basically you were right - problem is not with iterating but with my response.

Comment: Hmmm. I see. Awesome!